# Harmonic Series divergence - induction proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

I'm trying to show that the Harmonic series diverges, using induction. So far I have shown: If we let $s_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$

1. $s_{2n} \geq s_{n} + \frac{1}{2}, \forall n$
2. $s_{2^{n}} \geq 1 + \frac{n}{2}, \forall n$ by induction

The next step is to deduce the divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. I know that it does diverge but I don't directly see how the above two parts help.

Can I just say that since $s_{2^{n}} \geq 1 + \frac{n}{2}$ then as n tends to infinity, the partial sums of $s_{2_{n}}$ diverge? But that's for $s_{2^{n}}$ and not $s_{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):s_{2^n}\geqslant1+\frac n2$ and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac n2=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{2^n}=\infty$. Therefore, the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges, since its subsequence $(s_{2^n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges.

Comment: but isn't $s_{2^{n}}$ different to $s_{n}$?

Comment: Sure. But every subsequence of a convergente sequence converges too.

Comment: Ah, so just apply that but using divergent instead of convergent? I'm just not quite seeing how we can go from saying $s_{2^{n}}$ diverges (i understand this) to $s_{n}$ diverges. (Unless it's using the above that I just mentioned).

Comment: Given a sequence, asserting that if it converges then every subsequence converges too is *the same thing* as asserting that if some subsequence diverges, then the whole sequence diverges too. That's what I've used.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!